# How to handle WM_QUERYENDSESSION message in a multi-process Win32 application?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++

I have a win32 application spawns multiple long running processes.

In the main process (which creates the UI and spawns the worker processes) I'm handling `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` to block shutdown in case my application is doing something critical that would cause data corruption. The problem is that even before the main process receives `WM_QUERYENDSESSION`, Windows kills the child process (which have no special `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` handling), leaving the application in an invalid state.

What is the proper way to handle `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` in this case? Do I have to handle the message in each child process and somehow coordinate shutdown across all processes, or is there a way to tell Windows that the child processes should not be killed on shutdown and instead the main process will be responsible for their cleanup?

Comment: Yes it's per-process. Also have a read of: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20170329-00/?p=95855

Comment: The correct way to block shutdown during a critical operation is to use [`ShutdownBlockReasonCreate()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376877.aspx). Also see [Shutdown Changes for Windows Vista](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb394721.aspx)

Comment: What do you do if the mains voltage drops out? Handle that any way other than adding a battery and this problem goes away.